# tailwind: customize a xxx base color without loosing clases like xxx-100, xxx-200

Tags: colors, customization, tailwind-css, color-scheme

I want to define a text-blue color in tailwind.css without loosing text-blue-100, text-blue-200, etc.

I follow this guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#extending-the-defaults

and I try with:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        blue: '#5F99F7'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But all the text-blue-xxx disapear

Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the DEFAULT keyword if you want the class to be `text-blue`. You also need to make blue an object.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        blue: {
          'DEFAULT': '#5F99F7'
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: YES, that's exactly what I was looking for, BTW, where is it documented?

Comment: It's documented here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-object-syntax but it really belongs inside the extending the defaults section as well.